# Evalute this integral using stoke's theorem

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis, contour-integration

$\int \bar F \cdot d \bar r $where $\bar F=(x-y)i+(y+z)j+xk $ and $C$ is boundary of the area of the triangle cut-off from the plane $2x+y+z=2$ by the coordinate axis. 
I tried to solve this question-Stoke's theorem $$ \int \bar F \cdot d\bar r=\iint \bar N \cdot (\nabla \times \bar F)ds$$
So i got $$\bar N=\frac {(2i+j+k)}{\sqrt 6}$$
and $$\nabla \times \bar F=-i-j+k$$
$$\iint \bar N \cdot (\nabla \times \bar F)ds=\frac {-2}{\sqrt 6}\iint ds $$
but i am stuck here what to do next....

Comment: This has nothing to do with eigenvalues/eigenvectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $$\iint_Sds = Area(S)$$ so you should just calculate the area of the triangle, which shouldn't be too hard.

Hence, the solution will be $$\frac{-2}{\sqrt{6}}Area(S)$$

with $S$ the area of the triangle cut-off from the plane by the coordinate-axis.